# Can drive clone software copy the Volume Serial Number (Volume ID)?

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla, acronis-trueimage

On Windows, running `vol id c:` shows something like `4D12-7GG8`.

Is this Volume Serial Number copied when using disk cloning software such as CloneZilla or Acronis True Image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the volume label and the serial number are part of the filesystem metadata, not the hardware, and are copied by every tool which makes a direct block copy of the entire partition (as opposed to copying just the files to a brand new filesystem).

However, some cloning tools may deliberately set a new serial number to reduce confusion when both disks are connected to the same system.

Comment: Serial number is part of the drives firmware and cannot be altered.

Comment: @Moab: There's more than one kind of "serial number". The one in OP's post (and in the `vol` command) is pretty clearly the one from the FAT filesystem header. [Microsoft has a tool to change it.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/volumeid)

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain but I do not think so. The volume serial number of the target device will be different as these are part of the drive and not any software  (and so the source serial number cannot be used on any other device). So no point to copying it.